# Why can we solve eigenvalue problems which are non-convex by Lagrange multiplier methods and get global minima?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, lagrange-multiplier

while reading the paper "Some Modified Matrix Eigenvalue Problem" by Golub this doubt occurred to me. 
there he writes that we can minimize $x^TAx$ subject to $x^TBx=1, Cx=0$

As far as I understand Lagrange multiplier give us global minima only when the problem is convex however this problem is non-convex ($x^TBx=1$ is not affine). Could someone clarify ?

Comment: What is the question? A Lagrange multiplier exists at an extremum when the active constraint gradients are linearly independent, regardless of convexity. One needs to know an extremum exists first...

Comment: sorry about $x^TAx=0$ I meant $x^TAx$. corrected the question. Basically my question is that even though lagrange multipliers exist regardless of convexity, you only get global minimization when the problem is convex. yet eigen values are globally minimal. How does that work out

Comment: What do you mean by 'eigen values are globally minimal'? There must be conditions on $A,B,C$ for a solution to exist. Are you solving a generalised eigenvalue problem?

Comment: Yes I am solving a generalized eigenvalue problem constrained to the set $Cx=0$. A, B, C given values.  What I meant was that while eigen vectors are guaranteed to be global minimizers (over all possible eigen vectors) but lagrange multiplier methods can come up with "false" solutions which are not global minima. So do we have to prune away the "false" solutions ?

Comment: In general, yes.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Lagrange multiplier technique, then you get a (maybe) long list of candidates for global minima. Then you can evaluate the function to minimize over these set of candidates.

However, this method is not very efficient in general. It may work for special cases, where something about the structure of the problem is known.

Comment: Got it, and if let's say my list of candidates has only one candidate, then that candidate would necessarily be the global minima because our solution space is bounded ?

Comment: You need to know a solution exists first. Then you need to ensure that the appropriate conditions exist for a Lagrange multiplier to exist. Then you use this to characterize a hopefully finite (or manageable in some way) set of possible solutions and, finally, select from this set the one that has minimum value.